# Can you use a dynamic selector that doesn't stay consistent with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, puppeteer

I'm trying to find a selector that will stay fairly consistent through the entire process and there's 3 buttons that needs to be clicked to get to the create account page. On the third button there's no static or original selector I could find. There was an a `id=""` tag that I used and kept getting errors until I realized it changes every time the page is refreshed. I saw that if there was an consistency within it, you could do `"a[id="product*"]`, but unfortunately the entire ID changes. Is there anyway to have the selector as `"a[id=""]` and dynamically scrape the ID as it changes? Below is two examples of the ID changing as the page is refreshed.

[image: link with random id]

[image: same link with another random id]

[image: Updated Image]

Comment: This isn't much to work with. Can you share a fuller markup and the code you're using? Oftentimes, identifiable characteristics in a parent element make it easy to select a child. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the picture so you can see more and as for code, I have the selector as "const joinUsBtn3 = `a[text()="Junte-se a nós"]`"

Comment: That helps but best [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Looks like there's a class right in the parent element. Not sure if it's unique, but `.current-member-signin a` should work. Also, you're showing devtools, and sometimes those elements aren't visible in Puppeteer if your bot is blocked or if there's an iframe or shadow root in the parent tree. The selector you're showing is part of an XPath, not a CSS selector. The answer that was deleted is a reasonable one, if you select by XPath text you can then click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may assume that to select an element, you have to use only that element. But if there are no reliably identifiable characteristics on that element, work back up the tree and check parents for identifiable characteristics.

In your case, the enclosing `<div>` has plenty of unique-looking static class names you can use:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

const html = `
<div class="nike-unite-component action-link loginJoinLink current-member-signin">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Junte-se a</a>
</div>
<script>
// for testing
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
  target.textContent = "clicked";
});
</script>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const sel = ".loginJoinLink.current-member-signin a";
  const el = await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  await el.click();
  console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent)); // => clicked
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

The assumption here is that there's only one element with the CSS selector `.loginJoinLink.current-member-signin a`, or that the one you want is the first in the document. If the assumption isn't true, you can always strengthen the selector, for example,

```
.loginJoinLink.current-member-signin.action-link.nike-unite-component > a
```

(I typed this in from your screenshot, so please test it for typos).

If that's still not enough to disambiguate, add additional parent context:

```
#nike-unite-loginForm .loginJoinLink.current-member-signin a
```

XPath with a text selector is another option:

```js
const link = await page.waitForXPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Junte-se a')]");
```

The assumption here is that the substring `Junte-se a` is unique text inside `<a>` tags within the document, or that the one you want to click is the first.

If neither works, please provide a [runnable, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code and the actual site or representative markup. Oftentimes, there are iframes, shadow DOM roots, script blocking, visibility and other factors that make code like this fail on certain sites.

For example, visibility impacts how Puppeteer's trusted `.click()` works, so it may be necessary to use the untrusted native click:

```js
await el.evaluate(el => el.click());
```

Comment: it worked like a charm! (The first solution with the HTML), would I essentially do the same thing for the other DOMs? there's another DOM I'm trying to capture and I have it as "input[class="nike-unite-text-input emailAddress nike-unite-component"]", but i don't think it's a valid selector because puppeteer is failing to waitForSelector and .click(). Here's what I'm looking at https://imgur.com/a/KGT4YGh.png

Comment: Try `"input.nike-unite-text-input.emailAddress.nike-unite-component"`. It's odd to specify the class as an attribute string in a CSS selector. The period syntax is much cleaner and is agnostic of ordering and extra classes that you didn't include. It's testing an exact match. Yes, the first solution should work on pretty much any site, as long as the selector is correct and isn't in an iframe or shadow DOM, is visible, loads quickly enough, etc.